# The linkCaption field is blank in the Facebook Unity SDK FB.Feed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using the Facebook SDK for the Unity gaming engine and building to Android. When I attempt to run FB.Feed() and pass strings for the method's variables, the feed dialog appears and everything seems fine. When, however, I check Facebook for my post, I notice the linkCaption is not visible. The visibility of linkCaption seems to depend on what link I use for the link parameter: if I use "www.google.com" the caption shows up perfectly, but if I use my app's facebook page, "https://facebook.com/thegameZylum", it doesn't show up at all. I have no idea what's going on...any ideas?

Also, does anyone know how to make the share dialog that can be used with Android or iOS natively work with the Unity SDK? I would prefer using that to the Feed method, but I'll be alright using that if only I can get that caption to show up.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Feed

linkCaption - A short description, rendered below linkName in the story. **Ignored if sharing a Google Play or iTunes App Store link**

linkDescription - A longer description, rendered as the main body of the story. **Ignored if sharing a Google Play or iTunes App Store link**